# Volume of a solid in $xyz$-space

Tags: integration, volume

Calculate the volume of the solid in $xyz$-space bounded by the surfaces
$$
\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1} and\:z=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+4}
$$

---

I haven't done triple integrals for a long time. But it looks like we can use a coordinate change (cylindrical or spherical?) to make it simpler. And help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=r \sin \theta,y=r \cos \theta$, and the volume is, removing $\theta$ having noticed that the graph is unchanged after a rotation about the $z$ axis,

$$V=\int_{r \ge 0}2 \pi r\left(\frac{1}{r^2+1}-\frac{1}{r^2+4} \right)dr= \int_{u \ge 0} \pi \left(\frac{1}{u+1}-\frac{1}{u+4} \right)dr= \pi \int_1^4\frac{1}{u}du=\pi\ln(4).$$

Note that I've used that the volume of a cylinder with height $z$, thickness $dr$ and radius $r$ is $2 \pi r z dr$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cylindrical coordinates.  Then $x^2+y^2=r^2$.  You now have a solid of revolution, revolving a curve that looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201/%28x%5E2%2b4%29%20%3C%20y%20%3C%201/%28x%5E2%2b1%29) around the $x$ (or $r$) axis.  A plot is [image: below].  Now you should be able to integrate this.  I would suggest shells are easier.